# Qual a origem da interjeição tchê?

Tags: origem-histórica, interjeições

O povo gaúcho (viventes do sul do Brasil) tem como costume por vezes usar em suas frases a interjeição tchê.

> Exemplo:
>       Tchê, hoje ta um frio de renguear o cusco.
>       Esse guri nem sabe o que tá fazendo, tchê.

Entre muitos outros exemplos.

Gostaria de saber da origem dessa interjeição

Comment: @Jacinto então isso é uma interjeição... kkkk

Comment: Prefixo e sufixo não é de certeza. Se vires o edit, eu expliquei lá o que eles são. Pelos teus exemplos, parece-me uma [interjeição](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjei%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: Os habitantes de São Tomé e Príncipe também costuma usar essa interjeição.

Comment: @JorgeB. Interessante.  E tu sabes qual a grafia que usam ?

Comment: @Centaurus os São Tomenses costumam escrever *xeh* ou *xê*. Costumam usar em tom de admiração como por exemplo, *xeh, estás mesmo a dizer isso de mim?*

Comment: Então, e entre nós há quem diga *xi*, também para expressar admiração.

Answer (score 6):

Há um [artigo em Castelhano sobre **che** na Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Che). **Chê** é a grafia Castelhana de **tchê**. Diz que a origem não é consensual, e identifica várias possibilidades, entre as quais, as indicadas nas outras respostas:

- [Guarani](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_guarani), onde a palavra significa *eu* ou *meu*, pronunciada *tchê* no nordeste argentino, e *xê* no Paraguai.
- [Mapuche](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapuches), falado no sul do Chile, onde a palavra siginica *gente*
- [Quechua](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguas_quechuas) falado no norte do Peru e Equador, significando  *ouve/ouça* (tu/você imperativo).
- [De Veneza](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_v%C3%AAneta), donde vieram muitos imigrantes para a Argentina, da palavra *ció*, pronunciado *tchó*. Na região de Veneza diz-se *che vol, ció?* ou *que queres, tchó?*
- [Valenciano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_valenciana), variedade de Catalão, onde se escreve *xe* e se pronuncia *ché* (ou *tché*?).

Comment: Achei muita graça quando topei com o "che" valenciano, pensei "ô, gente, que conexão inusitada com os pampas!".

Comment: E os valencianos usam-no do mesmo modo? O artigo não é completamente claro sobre isso. Eu estava a leste destes *tchês* todos.

Comment: Nunca fui atrás da etimologia, do que tenho entendido e tal como uso, é uma interjeição tipo "nossa", "puxa", "pôxa, "epa"" (ptBR).

Comment: Aqui em Portugal há quem diga _tchiii, xiii_ para exprimir admiração. Às tantas isto são tudo manifestações dum fenómeno mais generalizado do que se julga. Eu tenho tendência para o _eh pá_, provavelmente relacionado com o _epa_ brasileiro, mas claramente duas palavras (porque aqui se parecem ser duas palavras é porque são mesmos duas no mínimo).

Comment: É fato, tinha esquecido do "xi", mas ali por Espirito Santo/Minas Gerais é usado mais para no contexto de "xi, deu melda"...

Comment: Também aqui se usa assim.

Comment: @Jacinto "Tchê" e "xi" são interjeições bem diferentes. "Tchê" é regionalismo gaúcho, e tem função fática; significa mais ou menos, "estou iniciando/continuando comunicação com você". Também se usa para expressar admiração: *Tchê, o Grêmio empatou em casa com o São Borja!*, caso em que é comum usar a expressão "Tchê, barbaridade!". Já "xi" é usada no Brasil inteiro, inclusive no Rio Grande do Sul, e geralmente expressa desagrado com o que se vai falar a seguir: *Xi, a polícia chegou*; *Xi, acho que estou com dor de barriga*.

Answer (score 5):

Tchê é uma interjeição usada por gaúchos (pessoa nascida no Rio Grande do Sul, e também em terras vizinhas como o Uruguai e nordeste da Argentina) e tem o sentido de "cara", "mano", "amigo", "meu chapa". Acho (opinião pessoal) que de certa forma corresponde ao "Ô meu!" dos Paulistas.

> Existem duas versões para a expressão, uma que tem origem nos índios, e outra de origem espanhola. Uma antiga tribo indígena da patagônia chamada Mapuche, que quando queriam chamar as outras pessoas de gente, diziam che. Já a versão espanhola, para abreviar a expressão “gente do céu”, diziam apenas “Che!”, para expressar qualquer sentimento de espanto, susto, ou qualquer exclamação. Para os espanhóis, che era a forma de apelar para Deus, mas também de chamar as pessoas.
>
> Com a descoberta da América, os colonizadores espanhóis trouxeram essa expressão para as colônias da América do Sul, e como o Rio Grande do Sul é um estado ao lado, acabaram incorporando o tchê em seu vocabulário, que é utilizado até hoje, por pessoas de todas as idades, e de toda a parte do estado. [Significados.com.br](http://www.significados.com.br/tche/)

Answer (score 3):

**Tchê** é uma interjeição coloquial usada por gaúchos (sul riograndenses) e por povos vizinhos do Rio Grande do Sul (Uruguai e Argentina).

É uma expressão de saudação, exclamação para se referir a alguém e tem o mesmo significado de **cara**, **amigo** ou afins.

Existem duas versões para a origem da expressão. Uma delas diz que ela teve origem do espanhol "che", uma interjeição semelhante a "ei".

A outra versão diz que a expressão teve suas origens no guarani da população indígena. Dependendo de seu uso, ela pode significar "eu", "meu" e também "amigo".

Não tenho fontes muito confiáveis de que **realmente** seja isso, mas foi assim que eu aprendi.